# Merging two tables with different key columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data frames `A` and `B`, where `A` looks like:

```
col1   col2 
USA    100
FR     99
UK     120
```

and `B` looks like:

```
col1        colx 
USA teext    12
text FR      9
text UK      2
```

Now, I want to merge the data frames `A` and `B` using `col1`, resulting in:

```
col1   col2  colx
USA    100    12
FR     99     9
UK     120    2
```

However, as you can see the values in the `col1` column in the two data frames are not exactly equal. In df `B` there is more text around the values, which I want to ignore when merging the two data frames. Anyone an idea how to do this with `merge` in pandas? Possibly with using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get value by column `df1['col1']` to new column, so possible `merge`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df1['col1'])
df2['col11'] = df2['col1'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df2)
        col1  colx col11
0  USA teext    12   USA
1    text FR     9    FR
2    text UK     2    UK

df = df1.rename(columns={'col1':'col11'}).merge(df2, on='col11')
print (df)
  col11  col2       col1  colx
0   USA   100  USA teext    12
1    FR    99    text FR     9
2    UK   120    text UK     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. We can't `merge` both `DataFrame` directly. You have to use `Regular Expression` for the Merging Process. Before moving ahead, the basic need for merging `DataFrame A` and `DataFrame B` is that they both contain `Same Column` and `Same Data` within it. So, for achieving that thing, you can see that we have to `trim` extra content from `DataFrame B`. After that we can easily use `pd.merge()` Operation on it. So, the Code for the same Scenario was stated below:-

```
# Import all-important Libraries
import pandas as pd
import re

# Reproducing given data of Column 'A'
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['USA', 'FR', 'UK'],   
    'col2': [100, 99, 120] 
})

# Print records of Column 'A'
A
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    col1    col2
0   USA     100
1   FR      99
2   UK      120
```

```
# Reproducing given data of Column 'B'
B = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['USA teext', 'text FR', 'text UK'],   
    'colx': [12, 9, 2] 
})

# Print records of Column 'B'
B
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    col1        colx
0   USA teext   12
1   text FR     9
2   text UK     2
```

After the reproduction of `DataFrame`, you can see the pattern that `Country` has been in the `Capital` Format. and the `text` which we have to `trim` was in `Small` format. So, we can do this task using `re` Library.

```
# Find Pattern in Column'B' and Convert Dataset of Column 'B' Same as 'A'
B.replace('[a-z ]','',regex = True, inplace = True)

# Verify by Printing Records of 'B'
B
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    col1    colx
0   USA     12
1   FR      9
2   UK      2
```

As you can see, we have finally achieved `col1` of `DataFrame B` same `col1` of `DataFrame A`. So, we can now move towards our merging operation:-

```
# Finally you can now merge both 'DataFrame' Easily
merged_df = pd.merge(left=A,right=B, left_on='col1', right_on='col1')

# Print Merged 'DataFrame'
merged_df
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    col1    col2    colx
0   USA     100     12
1   FR      99      9
2   UK      120     2
```

As you see we have achieved our desired `Output`. Hope this Solution helps you.